# How to read text between xml tags in a string using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, algorithm, azure-language-understanding

**Input String:**

`Can you book a flight from <SrcAirport> Detroit </SrcAirport> to <DestAirport> Chicago </DestAirport>?`

**Expected Output:**

```json
{
    "utterance": "Can you book a flight from Detroit to Chicago?",
    "entities":[
        {
            "name": "SrcAirport",
            "value": "Detroit"
            "startPosition": "27"
            "endPosition": "33"
        },
        {
            "name": "DestAirport",
            "value": "Chicago",
            "startPosition": "38"
            "endPosition": "44"
        }
    ]
}
```

**More Information:**

**startPosition:** *This is the index of the string where the word begins in the generated utterance string.*

**endPosition:** *This is the index of the string where the word ends in the generated utterance string.*

Comment: I know nothing about LUIS, but you can use regex to find where the tags are located and go from there.

Comment: Are you using LUIS? It should do this sort of thing for you. Flight booking with Source and Destination entities is one of the core samples.

Comment: @billoverton: I am trying to build an engine with which I can train Luis efficiently. Here's my API with Utterance Generator (expander) with Entity Labeling. https://rapidapi.com/akashpavate58/api/nlp-helper

Comment: Refer to this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-get-started-get-intent-from-browser?tabs=V2-1-2%2CV2-2-2%2CV3-3-1#use-the-browser-to-see-predictions for V2 prediction, if you are using V3 set verbose falg to true to get the data you need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-get-started-get-intent-from-browser?tabs=V2-1-2%2CV2-2-2%2CV3-3-1#use-the-browser-to-see-predictions

Answer (score 0):

Here's an API that can do this.
https://rapidapi.com/akashpavate58/api/nlp-helper